# Where is the user "shadows+" (shadowsocks?) defined?

Tags: systemd, users, shadowsocks

I am running the `ss-server` proxy (from the `shadowsocks-libev` package) on Ubuntu.

I believe `ss-server` is run by `systemd`.  `ss-server` is running as user `shadows+`, as can be seen below:

```
$  ps u -C ss-server
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
shadows+  719498  0.0  0.7  16244  7976 ?        Ss   Nov30   0:06 /usr/bin/ss-server -c /etc/shadowsocks-libev/config.json
$  ps un -C ss-server
    USER     PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
   64677  719498  0.0  0.7  16244  7976 ?        Ss   Nov30   0:06 /usr/bin/ss-server -c /etc/shadowsocks-libev/config.json
```

Where is this `shadows+` user defined?  I do not see this user listed in `/etc/passwd`.

It is possible that the actual username is something like `shadowsocks`, and it is being truncated down to 8 characters.  But even so, that user is not present in `/etc/passwd`.

So the question remains, where is this user defined?

**UPDATE:**

In response to telcoM's answer, I will provide additional background information that explains why I am curious about the `shadowsocks-libev` user.

`ss-server` runs (at least at present) as user 64677.

`ss-server` reads its configuration file `/etc/shadowsocks-libev/config.json`.

This configuration file (as installed by default on Ubuntu) is readable by any user.

This configuration file contains (by default) a semi-confidential password (that was presumably generated when the package was installed on the system).

Ideally, only the `ss-server` program, and any `ss-client` programs that connect to `ss-server` would know this password.

Therefore, the fact that the config file is readable by any user is, IMO, a (mild?) security vulnerability.

I was thinking about changing the ownership of `/etc/shadowsocks-libev/config.json` (or its parent directory).  So I'm wondering if this numeric user ID will be stable across reboots.

**SECOND UPDATE:**

Thanks to telcoM's answer and comments, I found the following file:
`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/shadowsocks-libev.service`

```
#  This file is part of shadowsocks-libev.
#
#  Shadowsocks-libev is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This file is default for Debian packaging. See also
#  /etc/default/shadowsocks-libev for environment variables.

[Unit]
Description=Shadowsocks-libev Default Server Service
Documentation=man:shadowsocks-libev(8)
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
DynamicUser=true
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/shadowsocks-libev
LimitNOFILE=32768
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ss-server -c $CONFFILE $DAEMON_ARGS

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that the above file contains `DynamicUser=true`.  The file lacks a `StateDirectory=` entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check the `passwd:` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

You'll very likely find it says `passwd: compat systemd`. If that's true, then your system is using `systemd-userdbd.service` in addition to the classic `/etc/passwd` for looking up user information. This allows software packages to easily add and remove application-specific user accounts by dropping appropriate JSON files to `/usr/lib/userdb/` or `/etc/userdb/` (or `/run/userdb` for use with containers and the like).

For more information, read `man nss-systemd` on your system, or [follow this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-systemd.html).

See what `getent passwd 64677` says, to look up the user account by its UID number and see the basic user information in a format that is analogous to an `/etc/passwd` line. That should at least reveal the full username, which you can then search for. For example, if you find that the username is actually `shadowsocks1`, you could run:

```
grep -r shadowsocks1 /etc /usr /run
```

This may produce a number of false hits, but if the user account has a persistent local definition, this should find it, no matter how it's defined.

`systemd-userdbd.service` can also support *dynamic users* that are "created" when a service is started and cease to exist when the service is shut down. Those will never be stored in `/etc/passwd` or any file at all. This feature was added in systemd version 232, and was expanded significantly in version 235. The range of UIDs used for dynamic users is 61184–65519 according to systemd documentation.

For more info: https://0pointer.net/blog/dynamic-users-with-systemd.html

Check the service definition of the systemd service that is running `ss-server`: if it includes `DynamicUser=yes`, then it confirms this feature is in use. To find out if the UID is persistent or not, see if the service definition includes a `StateDirectory=` definition or not. If a StateDirectory is defined, the UID number should be stable as long as the directory `/var/lib/private/<StateDirectory value>` is not deleted and the name of the service is not changed.

If the syntax of the `/etc/shadowsocks-libev/config.json` allows referring to other files for inclusion into the configuration, you could place the secret parts of the configuration into a file placed into the StateDirectory and `chown`ed appropriately; in this case, even if the dynamic UID has to change, systemd would automatically `chown` the state directory and its contents to match the new UID.

Comment: In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` I find `passwd: files systemd`.  Neither `/usr/lib/userdb/`, nor `/etc/userdb/`, nor `/run/userdb` exist.  However, I do find a socket at `/run/systemd/userdb/io.systemd.DynamicUser`.  `getent passwd 64677` outputs `shadowsocks-libev:x:64677:64677:Dynamic User:/:/usr/sbin/nologin`.  I will update my original question with some additional details about why I am asking about this user.

Comment: Edited my answer. Looks like systemd-userdbd now also has a feature for completely dynamic users. Personally, I think I see what this feature was meant for, but applying it to `shadowsocks-libev` without providing protection for passwords within its configuration might not have been a good choice from the packager...

Comment: Do you know, are the systemd "service definition" files stored in a consistent directory, or does their location vary from distro to distro?

Comment: I can't claim to know all distributions, but so far it looks like the directories are mostly consistent. The only inconsistency I'm aware of is that Debian and related distributions use `/lib/systemd` whereas others use `/usr/lib/systemd`. But Debian has also begun migrating to the modern style where `/bin`, `/sbin` and `/lib` are just symlinks to the corresponding directory under `/usr`, so this inconsistency will be going away eventually.

Comment: Note that there are multiple directories by design: `[/usr]/lib/systemd` is for files provided by package management **only**, `/etc/systemd` is for sysadmin's use (and any files in there will override corresponding files in `[/usr]/lib/systemd`), and `/run/systemd` is for dynamically auto-generated units and other non-persistent state.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!  I found the systemd service definition for `shadowsocks-libev` and added it to my question.